# Link 2 columns using VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm trying to connect two columns by finding a corresponding value between them , and then using it to add info to a 3rd column. Here's a small demo of what I have and what i want:

[image]
I want to fill that H column with info. Where's that info? Right here:

[image]

I want to copy info on Column B, Sheet 2, to Column H, Sheet 1, BASED on the 6 digit unique ID you see on both Columns A. It's fine if it doesn't find the ID on sheet 2.

Comment: where do you have problem, it seems to be simple VLOOKUP. Are 6-digits numbers in the second sheet not unique or something?

Comment: @MarcinSzaleniec only works if both Columns A match exactly (ID on sheet 1-row 1 equals ID on sheet 2-row 1 , etc) , but they obviously don't. ID on sheet 1-Column A-row 1 may very well be on sheet 2-Column A- row 244 , for example. "simple VLOOKUP" doesn't seem to work for me, or maybe i'm just doing this wrong and not realizing it? :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)
```

But I am still unsure if I understand the issue correctly. Values in both sheets must be numeric (or strings in both). Also, codes in the second sheet must appear only once. What else could go wrong. 
Ah, if you want to avoid #N/As, just use error catcher:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,0), "")
```